# How to make labels visible after using Clip to Current Data Driven Extent?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

I would like to use the Clip to current Data Driven Page extent feature, however, it covers up the labels that are already present, leaving visible features unlabelled. Does anyone know how to force ArcMap to draw the labels within the visible portion?

[image: example]